# How can i create order based click events

Tags: javascript, events

I'm trying to create a web based game for a toddler involving counting. I want to make it so they would click 1 through to 10 in order, so that they cant click say 3 until they have correctly clicked 1 and then 2 in order. Probably pretty easy, but I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to js. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you describe what you've tried so far?

Comment: Scott - to be honest I didnt even know where to start with the js.

Comment: @user2570816: Even if you don't have a clue yet about how to implement it in code, can you break down what you want done into bite-sized chunks?  That's a good first step...

Comment: Ok its been quite a while since I put this post in, but i finally got around to making some example code of what I wanted to achieve. So basically, i want it so that the user has to click on the numbers in order, if they get the right one, it disappears, if not it has a warning to say something like "Try again" http://jsfiddle.net/DMN9m/1/ is the example

Comment: user2570816: I'm afraid this is still not really not an attempt at the JS code, which is what I'd be willing to help with.  Try something.  It won't bite.

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to js, you may want to start learning JQuery.  I find it incredibly useful.  With it, you could do something like this:

```
 <button value='1'> 1 </button>
 <button value='2'> 2 </button>
 <button value='3'> 3 </button>
...

<script>
   var highest = 0;

   $('button').click( function() {
       if($(this).val() == highest+1)
       {   highest = $(this).val();   alert("yay!");  }
   });
</script>
```

This code will basically tell you 'yay!' every time you click the next number.